# Fibonacci sequence Javascript do while loop

Tags: javascript, do-while, fibonacci

I have been going through various threads and languages on this topic but I do not seem to find a solution for setting a bar for a fibonacci sequence to stop below 100 with a `do while` loop in Javascript.

```
var fbnci = [0, 1];
var i = 2;

do {
   // Add the fibonacci sequence: add previous to one before previous
   fbnci[i] = fbnci [i-2] + fbnci[i-1];
   console.log(fbnci[i]);
   fbnci[i]++;
} 
while (fbnci[i] < 100);
```

For some reason, the code above only runs once. What should I set the while condition to in order to keep printing the result until it reaches the closest value to 100?

Comment: You surely meant `i++;` instead of `fbnci[i] ++;`? And of course your looping condition needs to be adapted.

Comment: I think you meant to increment `i` not `fbnci[i]`

Comment: It doesn't make much of a difference whether you use a `do while` or normal `while` loop here. Go for the simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the code, it should be :

```
var fbnci = [0, 1], max = 100, index = 1, next;
do {
  index++;
  next = fbnci[index-2] + fbnci[index-1];
  if (next <= max) {
      console.log(next);
      fbnci[index] = next;
  }
} while(next < max);
```

Solution that prints all fib numbers that are lower than max.

Comment: That still doesn't work. Please try your code before posting.

Comment: ah, you're right, check is after :), Silly mistake - fixed, thanks @Bergi

Comment: It still prints past 100 (finishing at 144) why is that?

Comment: @HGB: Because it stops *after* having found an element above 100.

Comment: yes, it goes one by one, and if it is after 100 it stops executing the loop (but it already assigned the value). So your expectation is to stop before hitting number higher than 100 ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am not sure I understand how this works. How do I stop the sequences before the resulting `fbnci[i]` value reaches 100?

Comment: That works, thanks but it is definitely not as straightforward as I initially thought it would be. I am not sure I understand why index and next need to be split into two values.

Comment: you don't have to use `index`. It's there to make it bit more readable, instead of index you can do : `var next = fbnci[fbnci.length-2] + fbnci[fbnci.length-1];` and then do `fbnci.push(next);`. You can reorganize code a bit and do `while((next = fbnci[index-2] + fbnci[index-1])  < max) { fbnci.push(next); index++}` then it will be bit simpler, but you have assignment in condition which is bad practice. Next is there mostly for performance improv. you can go without it (you'll have to sum twice) I wrote is in the way `do { ... } while();` because you explicitly asked for it

Answer (score 1):

For me, it is an infinite loop that keeps printing out 1. You need to increment i instead of incrementing fbnci[i]:

`i++` instead of `fbnci[i] ++`

Additionally, you'll still fail the while condition, since you're checking a nil value. You'll want to change your while to check fbnci[i-1]:

`} while(fbnci[i-1]<100);`

Comment: good catch @Bergi, everyone focused on incremeting but no one thought about the while check.

Comment: This only gives me a ` NaN ` result.

Comment: @HGB really? it works for me (though it shows 144 as well, which has now been stated as going too far)

Answer (score -1):

The loop occurs only once because by the time `i=3`, your while condition is not able to check if `fbci[3] < 100` since `fbnci[3]` is `undefined`.

You can do this instead

```
var fbnci = [0, 1];
var i = 1;
while(fbnci[i] < 100) {
  fbnci.push(fbnci[i] + fbnci[i-1]);
  i++;
}

console.log(fbnci);
```

Comment: So it is not possible to use a while loop in this case?

Comment: you can do it via loop or functions. Functions have higher memory footprint because you need to keep the stack. Loops are bit trickier to implement but it's possible.

Comment: Loops also have a memory footprint since your fibonacci array is essentially a lookup table.

Comment: I downvoted because when I tested this answer, it still return an extra object that's is more than 100 in the array